# Uploading image to form and to S3 and webserver

Tags: javascript, php, forms, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Using these tutorials it looks like you can use post to upload an image straight to S3:

http://doc.s3.amazonaws.com/proposals/post.html

My question is though, what happens if my form has a text field (i.e Name) and a file upload. Is it possible to upload the file to S3 and still send my text field to my application on a single form submission?

This would allow me to have one form which not only uploads my file directly to S3 but also stores its name in my database without having to use javascript.

Comment: nice find. But isn't it just a proposal, instead of it being usable right now?

Comment: Seems to work, found a few tutorials which talk about it: http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-example-code/post/post_sample.html

Comment: Wowzers, it seems you stumbled unto some kind of time-machine. I can't imagine those tutorials are part of the official AWS docs. The tutorial refers to a AWS documentation page dated half 2006 and results in a 404. Best cause of action would be to find other tutorials online that talk about this feature to verify it does actually (still) exist. I hope you find some, but I highly doubt it. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It does seem to work, and here is some documentation.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingHTTPPOST.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HTTPPOSTExamples.html

Answer (score 0):

An HTML form can be used to upload files (eg images) directly to Amazon S3. Additional rules can be applied to restrict the upload to a particular path/name, filesize, bucket, etc. Uploads can also be performed to "private" buckets by providing authentication via an Access Key and calculated signature.

See documentation: [Browser-Based Uploads Using POST](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingHTTPPOST.html)

However, this will only upload the file to Amazon S3. It will not "send my text field to my application on a single form submission".